# How to compute the time spent in a form?

Tags: commcare

Today, you can compare now() and a specific time. In the current meta data there are two relevant values available in form data:

- started_time
- completed_time

For example:

```
I started completing a form on March 20th 2017 at 14:00:00
I submitted a form on March 20th 2017 at 14:05:05
I want to calculate the time it took to complete the form.
```

Can CommCare calculate the difference in duration for date and time form information?

Can I apply logic to see if the time of the interaction was more than five minutes, and return a true false response?

Can I use these properties to apply logic inside of the form?

Can this information be saved to a case property?

Is it possible to reference these values inside a form?

Can I have to use an integer function?

If yes, can I see the number of seconds that the user took to complete the form?

Answer (score 1):

You cannot directly access `timeStart` and `timeEnd` within a form.

However to figure out how much time has passed during a form, you can use a workaround by leveraging [Default Values and Calculate Conditions](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/103134/difference-between-default-value-and-calculate-condition)

If you create a hidden value, `time_start`, with the Default Value being `double(now())` this will be your start time since Default Values are only computed once and at the beginning of a form. Now create another hidden value, `time_end`, with the *Calculate Condition* being `double(now())`. Since Calculate Conditions are evaluated every time you answer a question, that time will continually update.

Now the elapsed time in a form is simply `time_end` - `time_start`. This will give you the output in days, which is somewhat unfortunate. In order to get to minutes you can do:

```
(time_end - time_start) * 24 * 60
```

If that value is greater than 5, then more than 5 minutes has passed. Once that value is saved to a hidden value, you can use it in all the ways you expect (saving to a case, and using in calculations). Hope that helps!